# Latest Versions of alexa-appkit and alexa-skills kit

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

From where does one obtain the latest versions of alexa-appkit-xx.xx.xx.jar and alexa-skills-kit-xx.xx.xx.jar?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest jar for the alexa-skills-kit here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.alexa/alexa-skills-kit
I don't see an appkit jar there, but if you mean the Alexa Voice Services SDK then that can be found here:
https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk

Answer (score 0):

for the latest updates and find a maven link have a look at
[this information](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/wiki/Setup-Guide)
Hope this helps you out a bit.